# Data validation in the model

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm not new to Laravel, but I'm probably making an architectural mistake somewhere.

I have a class (second layer above the model) where all the business logic is stored.
I need to validate incoming data, for example: to be email, to be in email format, to be unique, and so on.
A validator is great for this.

I COULD do this in the controller: `$request-validate()`. But I want to validate in the model itself because the method can be called from different places like `UserController` and `GraphQL::createUserMutation`.

Writing the same code in two places is a bad idea, isn't it?

In UserController:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  $request->all(),
  [
    'email' => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:20|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
  ],
);
    
if ($validator->fails()) {
 ...
}

User::query()->createUser($request->all());
```

And GraphQL createUserMutation:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  $request->all(),
  [
    'email' => 'email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|max:20|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
  ],
);
    
if ($validator->fails()) {
 ...
}

User::query()->createUser($request->all());
```

Therefore, I prefer to check in one place: in the model.

Everything works successfully if I return an array:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return $validator->messages();
}
```

But what if I want to throw an Exception?
I translate the error message to a string and throw an Exception:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($messages->toArray() as $field => $messagesList) {
  foreach ($messagesList as $msg){
   $result[] = '- '.$msg;
  }
}
throw new \Exception(implode("\n<br/>", $result));
```

How correct is my approach? Perhaps I am reinventing the wheel, but so far I have not found a better solution.
Or, still stick to the validation in the controller, duplicating the validation code?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing **Form Request Validation** in Laravel

**Step One:** Create a request by artisan command `php artisan make:request YourRequestName`

This will create a class named **YourRequestName.php** in directory **app\Http\Requests**

**Step Two:** Open this file you will find by default a **rule** function in which you will just return an array of your rules

**Step Three:** Add a function called **messages** in which you will return an array of validation messsages

**Step Four:** In any method in your project you want to use **YourRequestName** to make validation just inject it as a parameter instead of **Request Class**

An example of a request class **StoreRequest**:
[image: An example of a request class StoreRequest]

And in controller you will inject it like that:
[image]

And don't forget to use **StoreRequest Class** in your controller

And Finally this is the section in laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation